# Loops with callbacks in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have the following code in node.js

```
for (var i = 0; i<allLetters.length; i++)
   for (var k = 0; k<allLetters.length; k++){
        var allFilesName = fs.readdirSync("/opt/ + allLetters[i] + "/" + allLetters[k]);
        for (var t = 0; t< akkFilesName; t++)
              dosomething(allFilesName[t];
         }
```

`dosomething` is a function with callback, and include IO operation.

the problem is that my application doesn't executed the callback until it finish the `i, k & t` loops. Meaning, I see that all the CPU time is wasted on completed the callback, and just after it complete all the loops, it executed the callback, and returns from the callback.

I want that the loops and the callback will executed parallel, so I would get the result from the callback while I do the loop.

Comment: JS is single-threaded, so by default you will never have any work done "in parallel". Im further not quite sure what you want exactly: You want the results of your callbacks WITHIN your FOR-Loop? Or you just want the For-Loop to halt untill the callback return? If the latter, have a look at the `eachSeries()`-Function of the `async`-LIbrary: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: @Charminbear: Yes, I know it not parallel, but I want that callbacks would execute WITHIN my FOR-Loop. As I see it now, the callback execution is delayed until node.js is finish to deal with the for-loop. I want the the for loop would execute, and the callback too.

Comment: Then i think the `eachSeries()`-Function is the right thing for you.

Comment: @Charminbear: but then I wait until the callback is finished, no? And this is I/O operation and can be takes a long time..

Comment: @Charminbear: In other words, I want to execute my callback, and when it finish, the CPU would handle it.. Meanwhile, I want that the loop running would continue.

Comment: Then just use the `each`-Loop of async. It does the execution of the for-loop in parallel.

Comment: @Charminbear: Thanks. You can add this as answer, and I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the `each`-Function of the [async](http://github.com/caolan/async)-Library does what you are looking for.